# Calculate TextField width for hyperref form

Tags: hyperref, forms, textfield

I'm trying to create a Form with `hyperref`. This is what I've got so far. (I'll remove the boarder as well. But to see what I'm doing it is still there.)

[image]

I have a view issues with my current solution:

1. Is there some way, to calculate the `width` for the text fields automatically, so they will fill up the remaining space in the cell.
2. Why is there this small indentation at the start of the row, when I use `multicolumn`?

My current Idea is this:

- Add another parameter to `DefaultTextField` which is the current cell width
- Calculate the space needed for the label (Unfortunately, I have no Idea how to do this)
- Set the `TextField` width parameter to `width=#<paramnr>-/reservedspace`

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand\LayoutTextField[2]{%
    #1 \raisebox{-3.0pt}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\DefaultTextField}[2][]{%
    \mbox{\TextField[align=1,bordercolor=0 1 1,backgroundcolor={},#1]{#2}}%
}

\renewcommand\LayoutCheckField[2]{%
    \raisebox{-1.0pt}{#2}\hspace*{2mm}#1%
}
\newcommand{\DefaultCheckBox}[2][]{%
    \mbox{\CheckBox[bordercolor=0 0 0,backgroundcolor={},borderwidth=0.4mm,height=3mm,width=3mm,#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}L{0.5\textwidth}L{0.5\textwidth}@{}}
            \DefaultTextField[name=firstname,width=0.25\textwidth]{Firstname} & 
            \DefaultTextField[name=lastname,width=0.25\textwidth]{Lastname}\\ \hline
            
            \DefaultTextField[name=address1,width=0.25\textwidth]{Address} &
            \DefaultTextField[name=address2,,width=0.25\textwidth]{ZIP, City}\\ \hline
            
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\DefaultTextField[name=mail,width=0.25\textwidth]{E-Mail}}\\ \hline
            
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\DefaultTextField[name=phone,width=0.25\textwidth]{Phone/Mobile}}\\ \hline
            
            Foo\hfil\DefaultCheckBox[name=bar]{Bar}\hfil & \DefaultTextField[name=something,width=0.25\textwidth]{other} \\ \cline{2-2}
            
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\DefaultTextField[name=number,width=0.25\textwidth]{Something}}\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm maybe try using tabularx, and set the fields to the X columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get the width of the labels and then calculate the length:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand\LayoutTextField[2]{%
    #1 \raisebox{-3.0pt}{#2}%
}
\newlength\templength
\newcommand{\DefaultTextField}[2][]{%
    \settowidth\templength{#2 }%
    \mbox{\TextField[align=1,bordercolor=0 1 1,backgroundcolor={},#1,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\templength]{#2}}%
}

\renewcommand\LayoutCheckField[2]{%
    \raisebox{-1.0pt}{#2}\hspace*{2mm}#1%
}
\newcommand{\DefaultCheckBox}[2][]{%
    \mbox{\CheckBox[bordercolor=0 0 0,backgroundcolor={},borderwidth=0.4mm,height=3mm,width=3mm,#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
        \noindent
        \begin{tabular}{@{}L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}
            \DefaultTextField[name=firstname]{Firstname} &
            \DefaultTextField[name=lastname]{Lastname}\\ \hline

            \DefaultTextField[name=address1]{Address} &
            \DefaultTextField[name=address2]{ZIP, City}\\ \hline

            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=mail,width=0.25\textwidth]{E-Mail}}\\ \hline

            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=phone,width=0.25\textwidth]{Phone/Mobile}}\\ \hline

            Foo\hfil\DefaultCheckBox[name=bar]{Bar}\hfil & \DefaultTextField[name=something,width=0.25\textwidth]{other} \\ \cline{2-2}

            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=number,width=0.25\textwidth]{Something}}\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you. I learned some new tricks from this.