# Calculate TextField width for hyperref form - Multiple TextFields after CheckBox

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, forms, textfield

In reference to: [Calculate TextField width for hyperref form](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630683/calculate-textfield-width-for-hyperref-form)

The answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630701/294918 does mostly what I wanted when I found this question; ie: TextFields autosize.

I tried to modify the example to put a CheckBox followed by two TextFields on a single line/row.

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand\LayoutTextField[2]{%
    #1 \raisebox{-3.0pt}{#2}%
}
\newlength\templength
\newcommand{\DefaultTextField}[2][]{%
    \settowidth\templength{#2 }%
    \mbox{\TextField[align=1,bordercolor=0 1 1,backgroundcolor={},#1,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\templength]{#2}}%
}

\renewcommand\LayoutCheckField[2]{%
    \raisebox{-1.0pt}{#2}\hspace*{2mm}#1%
}
\newcommand{\DefaultCheckBox}[2][]{%
    \mbox{\CheckBox[bordercolor=0 0 0,backgroundcolor={},borderwidth=0.4mm,height=3mm,width=3mm,#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
        \noindent
        \begin{tabular}{@{}L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}
            \DefaultTextField[name=firstname]{Firstname} &
            \DefaultTextField[name=lastname]{Lastname}\\ \hline

            \DefaultTextField[name=address1]{Address} &
            \DefaultTextField[name=address2]{ZIP, City}\\ \hline

            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=mail,width=0.25\textwidth]{E-Mail}}\\ \hline

            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=phone,width=0.25\textwidth]{Phone/Mobile}}\\ \hline

            Foo\hfil\DefaultCheckBox[name=bar]{Bar}\hfil & \DefaultTextField[name=something,width=0.25\textwidth]{other} \\ \cline{2-2}

            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=number,width=0.25\textwidth]{Something}}\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

But in the following example, the 2nd \begin{tabular} environment doesn't work as expected/desired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand\LayoutTextField[2]{%
    #1 \raisebox{-3.0pt}{#2}%
}
\newlength\templength
\newcommand{\DefaultTextField}[2][]{%
    \settowidth\templength{#2 }%
    \mbox{\TextField[align=1,bordercolor=0 1 1,backgroundcolor={},#1,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\templength]{#2}}%
}

\renewcommand\LayoutCheckField[2]{%
    \raisebox{-1.0pt}{#2}\hspace*{2mm}#1%
}
\newcommand{\DefaultCheckBox}[2][]{%
    \mbox{\CheckBox[bordercolor=0 0 0,backgroundcolor={},borderwidth=0.4mm,height=3mm,width=3mm,#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
        \noindent
        \begin{tabular}{@{}L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}
            \DefaultTextField[name=firstname]{Firstname} &
            \DefaultTextField[name=lastname]{Lastname}\\ \hline
            
            \DefaultTextField[name=address1]{Address} &
            \DefaultTextField[name=address2]{ZIP, City}\\ \hline
            
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=mail,width=0.25\textwidth]{E-Mail}}\\ \hline
            
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=phone,width=0.25\textwidth]{Phone/Mobile}}\\ \hline
            
            Foo\hfil\DefaultCheckBox[name=bar]{Bar}\hfil & \DefaultTextField[name=something,width=0.25\textwidth]{other} \\ \cline{2-2}
            
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=number,width=0.25\textwidth]{Something}}\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    
        \vspace{10ex}   
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
        \noindent
        \begin{tabular}{@{}L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}
            \DefaultTextField[name=firstname]{Firstname} &
            \DefaultTextField[name=lastname]{Lastname}\\ \hline
            
            \DefaultTextField[name=address1]{Address} &
            \DefaultTextField[name=address2]{ZIP, City}\\ \hline
            
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=mail,width=0.25\textwidth]{E-Mail}}\\ \hline
            
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=phone,width=0.25\textwidth]{Phone/Mobile}}\\ \hline
            
            %Foo\hfil\DefaultCheckBox[name=bar]{Bar}\hfil & \DefaultTextField[name=something,width=0.25\textwidth]{other} \\ \cline{2-2}
            
            \DefaultCheckBox[name=bar]{Bar} & \DefaultTextField[name=something1]{other1} &  \DefaultTextField[name=something2]{other2}\\
            
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\DefaultTextField[name=number,width=0.25\textwidth]{Something}}\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well you get an error as you have declared only two columns but use three cells in the one line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have added an extra column to the begin{tabular}
 environment in "\section{Costs \& Dates}", but I am still having issues with the layout.

The final line now has a CheckBox, followed by two TextFields, on a single row. The problems is that there is a large gap between the CheckBox and the first TextField.

Tried to add a code example, but the code was not formatted as code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  The answer to my question and my followup question is in the following code `\begin{tabular}{@{}L{\dimexpr0.20\textwidth-\tabcolsep}L{\dimexpr0.4\textwidth-\tabcolsep}L{\dimexpr0.4\textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}`. This code shows a 3 column tabular environment with the correct column widths specified. `L{\dimexpr0.20\textwidth-\tabcolsep}L{\dimexpr0.4\textwidth-\tabcolsep}` defines a column (of (TextWidth * 0.2) -.\tabcolsep). Repeat this to get 3 columns (The sum of all column widths should add up to 1.0, otherwise the last column will overhang).